# SQL CASE and JOIN Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-query-store

I am writing a query using Join and CASE query on SQL but it iis not giving the desired result.

If I try running the count command it works individually, and if I try the other command, its running individually, but if I combine them, they are not working fine.

In this case, if I were to remove `COUNT(CCD_METHOD_OPTION_DESC.OPTION_ID)`, it works but adding it as below doesn't work.

```
SELECT COUNT(CCD_METHOD_OPTION_DESC.OPTION_ID) CASE
  when CCD_METHOD_OPTION_DESC.OPTION_ID = '1' then 'Option1'
  when CCD_METHOD_OPTION_DESC.OPTION_ID = '2' then 'Option2'
  when CCD_METHOD_OPTION_DESC.OPTION_ID = '3' then 'Option3'
  when CCD_METHOD_OPTION_DESC.OPTION_ID = '4' then 'Option4'
  when CCD_METHOD_OPTION_DESC.OPTION_ID = '5' then 'Option5'
  when CCD_METHOD_OPTION_DESC.OPTION_ID = '6' then 'Option6'
  when CCD_METHOD_OPTION_DESC.OPTION_ID = '7' then 'Option7'
  when CCD_METHOD_OPTION_DESC.OPTION_ID = '8' then 'Option8'
  when CCD_METHOD_OPTION_DESC.OPTION_ID = '9' then 'Option9'
  when CCD_METHOD_OPTION_DESC.OPTION_ID = '0' then 'Option0'
  else 'NoNumber'
  END AS Option_ID
  , METHOD_ID, CCD_METHOD_OPTION_DESC.CLIENT_ID, CCD_CALLS.DNIS, CCD_CALLS.ACCOUNT_NO
  , CCD_CALLS.LANG, CCD_CALLS.CCD_LAST_METHOD, CCD_CALLS.PERSON_ID
  , CCD_CALLS.ROUTE_CODE, CCD_CALLS.TRANSFER_TO, CCD_CALLS.CCD_END_CODE
  , CCD_CALLS.STARTDATETIME, CONVERT(char(10),CCD_CALLS.STARTDATETIME,101) as Date
  , CONVERT(char(20),CCD_CALLS.STARTDATETIME,108) as Interval_Time
  , CCD_CALLS.ENDDATETIME
from CCD_METHOD_OPTION_DESC
RIGHT JOIN CCD_CALLS ON CCD_CALLS.CLIENT_ID = CD_METHOD_OPTION_DESC.CLIENT_ID)
```

Essentially, I am trying to get a count of each option such as How many times each options 0-9 was selected with other information

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
SELECT COUNT(CCD_METHOD_OPTION_DESC.OPTION_ID) over(partition by CASE
  when CCD_METHOD_OPTION_DESC.OPTION_ID = '1' then 'Option1'
  when CCD_METHOD_OPTION_DESC.OPTION_ID = '2' then 'Option2'
  when CCD_METHOD_OPTION_DESC.OPTION_ID = '3' then 'Option3'
  when CCD_METHOD_OPTION_DESC.OPTION_ID = '4' then 'Option4'
  when CCD_METHOD_OPTION_DESC.OPTION_ID = '5' then 'Option5'
  when CCD_METHOD_OPTION_DESC.OPTION_ID = '6' then 'Option6'
  when CCD_METHOD_OPTION_DESC.OPTION_ID = '7' then 'Option7'
  when CCD_METHOD_OPTION_DESC.OPTION_ID = '8' then 'Option8'
  when CCD_METHOD_OPTION_DESC.OPTION_ID = '9' then 'Option9'
  when CCD_METHOD_OPTION_DESC.OPTION_ID = '0' then 'Option0'
  else 'NoNumber'
  END ) AS Option_ID_ct
  ,CASE
  when CCD_METHOD_OPTION_DESC.OPTION_ID = '1' then 'Option1'
  when CCD_METHOD_OPTION_DESC.OPTION_ID = '2' then 'Option2'
  when CCD_METHOD_OPTION_DESC.OPTION_ID = '3' then 'Option3'
  when CCD_METHOD_OPTION_DESC.OPTION_ID = '4' then 'Option4'
  when CCD_METHOD_OPTION_DESC.OPTION_ID = '5' then 'Option5'
  when CCD_METHOD_OPTION_DESC.OPTION_ID = '6' then 'Option6'
  when CCD_METHOD_OPTION_DESC.OPTION_ID = '7' then 'Option7'
  when CCD_METHOD_OPTION_DESC.OPTION_ID = '8' then 'Option8'
  when CCD_METHOD_OPTION_DESC.OPTION_ID = '9' then 'Option9'
  when CCD_METHOD_OPTION_DESC.OPTION_ID = '0' then 'Option0'
  else 'NoNumber'
  END AS Option_ID
  , METHOD_ID, CCD_METHOD_OPTION_DESC.CLIENT_ID, CCD_CALLS.DNIS, CCD_CALLS.ACCOUNT_NO
  , CCD_CALLS.LANG, CCD_CALLS.CCD_LAST_METHOD, CCD_CALLS.PERSON_ID
  , CCD_CALLS.ROUTE_CODE, CCD_CALLS.TRANSFER_TO, CCD_CALLS.CCD_END_CODE
  , CCD_CALLS.STARTDATETIME, CONVERT(char(10),CCD_CALLS.STARTDATETIME,101) as Date
  , CONVERT(char(20),CCD_CALLS.STARTDATETIME,108) as Interval_Time
  , CCD_CALLS.ENDDATETIME
from CCD_METHOD_OPTION_DESC
RIGHT JOIN CCD_CALLS ON CCD_CALLS.CLIENT_ID = CD_METHOD_OPTION_DESC.CLIENT_ID
```

Comment: When I try this query, I get a constant number across selected options. So in my case, when I look at the output, I see Option_ID_ct to be the same numbers for both options 1 and 2 and then options 3,4,and 9 have the same count as well.

Answer (score 0):

solution using WITH clause...

```
WITH count_options (count, OPTION_ID)  
AS  
(  
SELECT COUNT(*) as count
       CCD_METHOD_OPTION_DESC.OPTION_ID as OPTION_ID
  from CCD_METHOD_OPTION_DESC
 group by CCD_METHOD_OPTION_DESC.OPTION_ID
)  


SELECT count_options.COUNT, CASE
  when CCD_METHOD_OPTION_DESC.OPTION_ID = '1' then 'Option1'
  when CCD_METHOD_OPTION_DESC.OPTION_ID = '2' then 'Option2'
  when CCD_METHOD_OPTION_DESC.OPTION_ID = '3' then 'Option3'
  when CCD_METHOD_OPTION_DESC.OPTION_ID = '4' then 'Option4'
  when CCD_METHOD_OPTION_DESC.OPTION_ID = '5' then 'Option5'
  when CCD_METHOD_OPTION_DESC.OPTION_ID = '6' then 'Option6'
  when CCD_METHOD_OPTION_DESC.OPTION_ID = '7' then 'Option7'
  when CCD_METHOD_OPTION_DESC.OPTION_ID = '8' then 'Option8'
  when CCD_METHOD_OPTION_DESC.OPTION_ID = '9' then 'Option9'
  when CCD_METHOD_OPTION_DESC.OPTION_ID = '0' then 'Option0'
  else 'NoNumber'
  END AS Option_ID
  , METHOD_ID, CCD_METHOD_OPTION_DESC.CLIENT_ID, CCD_CALLS.DNIS, CCD_CALLS.ACCOUNT_NO
  , CCD_CALLS.LANG, CCD_CALLS.CCD_LAST_METHOD, CCD_CALLS.PERSON_ID
  , CCD_CALLS.ROUTE_CODE, CCD_CALLS.TRANSFER_TO, CCD_CALLS.CCD_END_CODE
  , CCD_CALLS.STARTDATETIME, CONVERT(char(10),CCD_CALLS.STARTDATETIME,101) as Date
  , CONVERT(char(20),CCD_CALLS.STARTDATETIME,108) as Interval_Time
  , CCD_CALLS.ENDDATETIME
from CCD_METHOD_OPTION_DESC
RIGHT JOIN CCD_CALLS ON CCD_CALLS.CLIENT_ID = CD_METHOD_OPTION_DESC.CLIENT_ID
INNER JOIN count_options ON count_options.OPTION_ID = CCD_METHOD_OPTION_DESC.OPTION_ID;
```